# How do you replace characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you in Javascript replace characters?  I need to replace '(' and ')' in this output to make this link work correctly.  Jquery would be ok too, but Javascript is usually faster on it's own.

```
function success(position) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var latlng1 = latlng.replace('(', '');
  var latlng1 = latlng1.replace(')', '');

  alert("http://www.google.com/maps/@"+latlng1+",17z");
}
```

For example my output of latlng (latitude, longitude) would show the ( ) in it:

(48.6617564,-102.98313889933997)

Comment: `LatLng` is a class.  `latlng` is an instance of that class.  You get the string representation by doing `latlng.toString()`, which is implicitly what happens when you concatenate to a string.  Doing `latlng.toString().replace('(', '').replace(')', '')` should do the trick.  I believe you could just do `"http://www.google.com/maps/@"+latlng.lat()+","+latlng.lng()+",17z"`

Comment: This works great!  Still learning about the Geolocations... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following regex

```js
 var latLng = "(48.6617564,-102.98313889933997)",
    latLng = latLng.replace(/([()])/g, '');

 console.log("http://www.google.com/maps/@"+latLng+",17z");
```